# How to test MySQL connection in PHP and Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making a PHP application installer (something like Wordpress installation script) and I need to check mysql connection using host name, username, password and database provided by user during installation.

I'm using this code as a Laravel controller method to test connection:

```
public function TestDatabaseConnection(){
    try {
        $database_host = Config::get('config.database_host');
        $database_name = Config::get('config.database_name');
        $database_user = Config::get('config.database_user');
        $database_password = Config::get('config.database_password');

        $connection = mysqli_connect($database_host,$database_user,$database_password,$database_name);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return false;

    }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to properly test the connection. Function return value (true/false) doesn't depend whether user supplies db data at all, or if db data is correct/incorrect..

Fils /app/config/config.php contains the following array:

```
<?php return array('database_host' => 'localhost', 'database_name' => 'dbasename',    'database_user' => 'dbuser', 'database_password' => 'pass');
```

and it's being updated via form during installation process.

Is there any way to modify this code or maybe you have some other code suggestions?

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: the question is in the title. I've also edited the body of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is:

> How to test MySQL connection in PHP and Laravel?

But then you are setting up a standard PHP MySQLi connection like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($database_host,$database_user,$database_password,$database_name);
```

Why would you do that? The whole purpose of using a framework is to work within the framework. And something that encompasses these two basic systems concepts:

- Read a configuration file.
- Establish a database connection.

Doing those things is something that pretty much every capable—and widely adopted—programming framework should be able to handle within it’s own structure & using it’s own methods.

So that said, looking at [the Laravel documentation on “Basic Database Usage”](http://laravel.com/docs/database) shows the following. This is placed in your DB configuration file located in `app/config/database.php.` :

```
'mysql' => array(
    'read' => array(
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ),
    'write' => array(
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

The example has two distinct DB connections: One for `read` and the other for `write`, but that is not how most DB connections for simple projects work. So you can set this instead also using your settings:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'host'      => Config::get('config.database_host'),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => Config::get('config.database_name'),
    'username'  => Config::get('config.database_user'),
    'password'  => Config::get('config.database_password'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Then to test that connection, you would just do this:

```
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{
   echo "Yes! successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}
```

But that said you are also saying:

> I'm making a PHP application installer…

Why reinvent the wheel when PHP build systems such as [`Phing`](http://www.phing.info/) exist?

Comment: In regards to Phing: Do you get what I'm trying to make? Something like Wordpress web installer. Is Phing capable of making something like that?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to distribute application to non-technically oriented people that don't know to use command line etc. Just to upload application and install it using step by step installation wizard.

Comment: Checking for getDatabaseName doesn't actually do anything with the database. It returns the value of the configuration variable in `.env`, so this doesn't work.

Comment: If you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432752/laravel-5-1-checking-a-database-connection, it seems that it is discouraged from using `DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()` to test a connection since it is misleading?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check whether the connection is made or not using this:

```
if(DB::connection()) {
    // connection is made
}
```

Because you don't need to make connection manually. If the user provided right credentials in the `app/config/database.php` then the user will be able to query in the database but if you need to check the connection then given code above is able to check because if the connection is not made then an error will be thrown and on a valid connection the `Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection` object will be returned. So, in this case it's also possible to use:

```
if(DB::connection() instanceof Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection) {
    // connection is made
}
```

So, according to your example of `TestDatabaseConnection` method you can do something like this:

```
public function TestDatabaseConnection(){
    // Returns Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection on successful
    // connection; otherwise an exception would be thrown if failed
    return DB::connection();
}
```

Comment: This won't work, Laravel `DB::connection()` returns an `Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection` object even if the DB doesn't exists or the credentials are wrong. The code will throw an exception later, when you'll try to query the DB.

Comment: Yes, it'll throw an exception so user will get that. To check if every required parameters are available. one should call `DB::connection()-> getConfig()` which will return an array but to check if a database is available, one must make a query, for example [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535229/check-database-if-exists-using-laravel). If credentials are invalid then the query will not success and in that case nobody will be able to check the credentials of `mySql`, all they can know that the credentials don't match by an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to catch the error of laravel db connection failure,
you can define this:

```
 App::error(function(PDOException $exception, $code)
 {
     die('do what you want here');
 });
```

I defined it inside:

```
/app/start/global.php
```

you can define it where ever you like.