# Laravel 5.1 - Checking a Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to check if a database is connected in Laravel.

I've looked around the documentation and can't find anything. The closest thing I've found is [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections), but this doesn't solve my problem.

I have three instances of MySQL that are set up on different machines. Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.

1. If database 1 is connected, save data to it
2. If database 1 is not connected, check if database 2 is connected
3. If database 2 is connected save data to it
4. If database 2 is not connected, check if database 3 is connected
5. If database 3 is connected, save data to it

To be clear, is there a way to check that a database is connected in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: The most obvious way would be to select something from the database within a try - catch. Whenever an exception is throwed the server / connection is not available (assuming there aren't any other errors - you might want to use the exception code here, to assure it's not a query problem (like missing a column or something)).

Comment: @milz That was my first thought, but I was hoping for a pre-existing method for this.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try just getting the underlying PDO instance.  If *that* fails, then Laravel was unable to connect to the database!

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

// Test database connection
try {
    DB::connection()->getPdo();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration. error:" . $e );
}
```

Comment: @YasserMoussa, you put it wherever you need to check for a working connection to the DB.

Comment: @alexw ok for example i need to use this code when laravel on first time boot so i used it in AppServiceProvider on boot() method and on catch die() worked but return view('errors.database') which i need didn't work it just showed laravel errors page .. am i missing something ?

Comment: Not sure - maybe try #laravel in Freenode IRC for help with your specific situation.

Comment: This won't work for me - getPdo() timeout is longer than nginx timeout and I don't want to mess with server configuration, I just want to check if I can access my database.

Comment: guys, you can create a route and add these code to test :D

Comment: I would recommend doing: die($e) for this gives the error message too, it's more clear than just a homemade message +1 though for finding this

Comment: How do we call this code every time not violating SOLID principles? This does not address this scenario.

Answer (score 121):

You can use [alexw's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40778219/5284749) solution with the Artisan. Run following commands in the command line.

```
php artisan tinker
DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

If connection is OK, you should see

> CONNECTION_STATUS: "Connection OK; waiting to send.",

near the end of the response.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original solution?

Comment: BTW, `php artisan tinker` `DB:connection()` can target any API public endpoint from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php` class, in particular, `getConfig()`, which is really convenient to get the information details to connect to the DB in presence, allowing you to try that connection manually from the client of your choice.

Comment: This is actually faster than write down a function

Comment: gotta love tinker! can confirm this is still best way today with Laravel 10.2

Answer (score 21):

You can also run this:

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

It makes a db connection connection to get migrations from migrations table. It'll throw an exception if the connection fails.

Comment: Beware this requires the DB user in the app to have access to the db information_schema to be successful

Answer (score 20):

You can use this, in a controller method or in an inline function of a route:

```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   //....
   try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();
        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
            echo "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        }else{
            die("Could not find the database. Please check your configuration.");
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        die("Could not open connection to database server.  Please check your configuration.");
    }
```

Comment: you can add this as inline function in routes (web.php) or in any controller method

Comment: As far as I've tested, it seems like the `->getDatabaseName()` part is not needed, since `->getPdo()` will already thrown an error (if I'm wrong I'll be happy to know that).

Answer (score 10):

You can use this query for checking database connection in laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
// ...
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

if($pdo)
   {
     echo "Connected successfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
   } else {
     echo "You are not connected to database";
   }
```

For more information, you can check out this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database.

Comment: This check appears to read from the configuration, not the active connection. This still reports connected succesfully if connection params are incorrect.

Comment: This code just returns values in configuration file!

Comment: **This answer is misleading. Anyone coming here must look at @alexw's answer below**

Comment: For later readers confused by the comments about this being a wrong answer when it seems to be basically the same as @alexw's, the reason is: this answer,used to read `if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())`, but after the comment feedback, the answer was updated to use `DB::connection()->getPdo()` instead

Comment: For later readers confused by the top two comments about returning configuration and not doing any checks, they are erroneous. Make sure you test by not changing the last digit in the localhost IP address (like. 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.23) as the 2nd address will still resolve to your localhost thus making this check useless.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this worked in that version of laravel, but at least on newer ones you can run

```
php artisan db
```

and if your app can access the database then you should see a cli repl for it, for postgres you will see a psql instance

Comment: in laravel 9 you can do `php artisan db:show`

Answer (score 0):

### Another Approach:

When Laravel tries to connect to database, if the connection fails or if it finds any errors it will return a `PDOException` error. We can catch this error and redirect the action

Add the following code in the `app/filtes.php` file.

```
App::error(function(PDOException $exception)
{
    Log::error("Error connecting to database: ".$exception->getMessage());

    return "Error connecting to database";
});
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Did you mean app/filters.php ? Missing an 'r' there. The question is laravel 5.1 and laravel structure in 5.1 doesn't use app/filters.php directory. That is for laravel 4.

Comment: From redbear's comment: @ArtisanBay's approach sounds like a working one. If filter is no longer available, perhaps you may try to write in a middleware.